# How do I calculate the dimensions of this Frustum?

Tags: trigonometry, 3d, solid-geometry

So, I saw this question in a book,

> You have been given a cone. The cone's base angles are both equal to
>   75° and the vertical angle is (of course) 30°.The radius of the cone
>   is 7 metres.Now, you cut the cone's top 1/3rd and are left with 2/3rd
>   of it(the frustum). Calculate the slant height of the cone and also
>   calculate the radius of the top surface formed after converting it
>   into a frustum.

Couldn't really understand how to do it. I'm just a High School student, so I'm not much aware as to how to solve such questions, so help requested here. Also, I was given the clue by a maths teacher that you may like to use Trigonometry, which I'm not really good at, so help out here.
Thanks in advance,
Nalin Bhardwaj

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  If you slice the cone with a plane through the axis, you have a $30-75-75$ triangle.  Bisecting the $30^\circ$ angle gives two right triangles.  You have the short leg from the radius, and trig will give the other legs-you need the tangent of $75^\circ$.  The hypotenuse is the slant height.  Presumably the top third you cut off is the top third of the altitude (not the volume), so that will make a similar triangle, giving the top radius. This is entirely a 2D problem once you slice the cone.

Comment: yes, I tried doing this but was told that I'm close but not correct, cause its common sense to do that once you know that youre supposed to use trigo, so any other methods or ways to do this required !

Comment: Probably you are on the right approach and have some minor error. If you show what you have done we can help.